# Datatable edit button functioning

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Below is the current script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/NewPopulation',
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: {},
                    success: function (data) {
                        var tr;
                        console.log(data);
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            tr = tr + "<tr>";
                            tr = tr + "<td style='display: none'>" + data[i].PollSurveyID + "</td>"
                            tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].PollSurveyName + "</td>";
                            tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].PollSurveyDescription + "</td>";
                            tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].CategoryName + "</td>";
                            tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].StartDate + "</td>";
                            tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].EndDate + "</td>";
                            tr = tr + "<td><a class='editRow' ><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></a></td>";
                            //tr = tr + "<td><input type='button' id='btnDelete' value='Delete' /><i class='fa fa - close'></i></td > ";
                            tr = tr + "<td><a class='delRow'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a></td>";
                            tr = tr + "</tr>";

                        }

                        $('#tblPopulation').append(tr);
                        tblFormate();
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        alert('No Valid Data');
                    }

                });


                $('#tblPopulation').on('click', '.delRow', function () {
                    var table = $('#tblPopulation').DataTable();
                    table
                        .row($(this).parents('tr'))
                        .remove()
                        .draw();
                });

                function deleteRow(row) {
                    var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
                    document.getElementById("#tblPopulation").deleteRow(i);
                }

                function tblFormate() {
                    var table = $('#tblPopulation').DataTable(
                        {
                            //"searching": false,
                            "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 50, 100, 150, -1], [5, 10, 50, 100, 150, "All"]]
                        });
                    //Apply the search
                    table.columns().eq(0).each(function (colIdx) {
                        $('input', table.column(colIdx).header()).on('keyup change', function () {
                            table
                                .column(colIdx)
                                .search(this.value)
                                .draw();
                        });
                    });
                }
            });

        </script>
```

This is JavaScript for my datatable having edit and delete buttons. For edit I tried many thing but didn't get response from the button. What I want is when I click edit button all details must get filled in below sections individually. Except the Name other controls are dropdown so that user can change the **category** or **status**.

My thought of doing so was to take a hidden column and take **PollId** in that column when I click edit button of a row **PollId** would be sent to a hidden textbox. Based on the textbox value all controllers get populated as I have a function which take **PollId** as a parameter and returns all the details against that Poll or survey.
Any other idea are welcomed. Attaching a picture of page to give a rough idea of flow.

[[image: ]]

Comment: this might be of help :https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1191769/Grid-View-with-AJAX-based-CRUD-Operations-in-ASP-N

Comment: I'm not seeing an onclick for your edit button or something like that in your code? Is the problem you're dealing with right now that it doesn't get redirected to the edit page? It's difficult to pinpoint exactly what you need help with, 'didn't get response from the button' leaves room for a lot of interpretation

Comment: @Snackoverflow removed onclick event for edit button before posting here. I had 3-4 types of event for edit button.

Comment: @Snackoverflow right now what i'm trying to do is when i click edit button the PollId which is hidden column of that row must be sent to a hidden textbox in below section based on that id i will populate all textboxes and dropdown. I dont know whether my approach is right or not.

Comment: And what was not working for your eventlister? Did it just not execute the function it should? Or were you having trouble writing the function?

Comment: on clicking the edit button i didn't get the response. Tried to retrieve the row data but nothing happened. Just the aim is to populate controller in below section with the same row data on which edit button is being click. Sorry this is vast @Snackoverflow